# Prove that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Bbb R^2.$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

> Let $\textbf {x} = (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2.$ For any subset $E \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ define $\textbf {x} E$ as follows $:$ $$\textbf {x} E : = \left \{(ax,by)\ |\ (a,b) \in E \right \}.$$ Prove that $\mathcal A = \left \{E \in \mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2}\ |\ \textbf {x} E \in \mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2} \right \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Bbb R^2.$

It is easy to see that $\varnothing, \Bbb R^2 \in \mathcal A.$ Also $\mathcal A$ is closed under countable unions. For that let us take a sequence $\{E_n \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ of elements in $\mathcal A.$ Need to show that $E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \in \mathcal A.$ For that we need only to show that $\textbf {x} E \in \mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2}.$

**Claim** $:$ $\textbf {x} E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \textbf {x} E_n.$

Let $y \in \textbf {x} E.$ Then $\exists$ $(a,b) \in E$ such that $y = (ax,by).$ Since $(a,b) \in E,$ $\exists$ $i \in \Bbb N$ such that $(a,b) \in E_i.$ But then $y = (ax,by) \in \textbf {x} E_i.$ Hence $y \in \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \textbf {x} E_n.$ This shows that $\textbf {x} E \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \textbf {x} E_n.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$

To prove the reverse inclusion let us take any $z \in \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \textbf {x} E_n.$ Then $\exists$ $j \in \Bbb N$ such that $z \in \textbf {x} E_j.$ So $\exists$ $(p,q) \in E_j$ such that $z = \textbf {x} (p,q) = (px,qy).$ But since $E_j \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n = E,$ it follows that $(p,q) \in E.$ This shows that $z=(px,qy) = \textbf {x} (p,q) \in \textbf {x} E.$ Hence $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \textbf {x} E_n \subseteq \textbf {x} E.\ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ (2)$

From $(1)$ anf $(2)$ it follows that $\textbf {x} E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \textbf {x} E_n.$ This proves the claim. Now since $E_n \in \mathcal A,$ for all $n \geq 1,$ it follows that $\textbf {x} E_n \in \mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2},$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Since $\mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Bbb R^2,$ we have $\textbf {x} E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \textbf {x} E_n \in \mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2}.$ This shows that $E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \in \mathcal A.$ Hence $\mathcal A$ is closed under countable unions.

The last thing what we have to show is that $\mathcal A$ is closed under complimentation. For that let $E \in \mathcal A.$ Then $\textbf {x} E \in \mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2}.$ Now I'm trying to prove that $\left (\textbf {x} E \right )^c = \textbf {x} E^c.$ But I don't think it's true. For instance let $E = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $\textbf {x} = (1,0).$ Then $\textbf {x} E = \{(t,0)\ |\ t \in [0,1] \}.$ Now $\left (\frac  1 2,2 \right ) \in E^c.$ Therefore $\textbf {x} \left (\frac  1 2,2 \right ) = \left (\frac 1 2,0 \right ) \in \textbf {x} E^c.$ Therefore $\textbf {x} E^c \cap \textbf {x} E \neq \varnothing.$ Hence $\textbf {x} E^c \subsetneq \left (\textbf {x} E \right )^c.$ The equality can only occur if the both the components of $\textbf {x}$ are non-zero. So how do I prove that $\mathcal A$ is closed under complimentation in case both the components of $\textbf {x}$ are not simultaneously non-zero? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Source** $:$ https://youtu.be/CjewMbxZzEQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to proceed by cases:

If $x≠0\wedge y≠0$, then the map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $(a,b)\mapsto(xa,yb)$ is a homeomorphism of the plane. In particular, it is invertible, measurable, and has measurable inverse. But then $\mathbf{x}E\in \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}\iff E\in\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}$, so $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Suppose that $x\cdot y=0$. Without loss of generality, $y=0$ (the other case is analogous, or can be deduced from this one by considering the homeomorphism $(a,b)\mapsto (b,a)$). Note that, if $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, then
$$
\mathbf{x}E=\{(xa,0b):(a,b)\in E\}\subset \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}
$$
The RHS has measure $0$, so $\mathbf{x}(E)\in\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ by completeness of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. But then $E\in\mathcal{A}$, so actually $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Oh! I see. Very nice argument of the case where $x.y=0.$ Thanks...

Comment: For the second case what I found is that $$\textbf{x} E = \bigcup\limits_{y \in \Bbb R} (xE^y) \times \{0 \}.$$ Now for each $y \in \Bbb R,$ $xE^y \in \mathcal L_{\Bbb R}.$ Now I got stuck. But I didn't observe the fact that in this case we actually have $\textbf {x} E \subseteq \Bbb R \times \{0 \}.$